# MySQL, Search for same columns in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

Let's say that we have the following table:

```
|--------|-------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| tbl_id | tbl_item_id | tbl_data_a | tbl_data_b | tbl_data_c | tbl_data_d |
|--------|-------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|      1 |           1 |         a1 |         b1 |         c1 |         d1 |
|      2 |           1 |         a2 |         b2 |         c2 |         d2 |
|      3 |           1 |         a3 |         b3 |         c3 |         d3 |
|      4 |           2 |         a1 |         b1 |         c1 |         d1 |
|      5 |           2 |         a2 |         b2 |         c2 |         d2 |
|      6 |           3 |         a1 |         b1 |         c1 |         d1 |
|      7 |           4 |         a1 |         b1 |         c1 |         d1 |
|      8 |           4 |         a2 |         b2 |        c22 |         d2 |
|--------|-------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
```

How can we get the tbl_item_id that is has all the correct column data for all the provided rows?

---

For example, we have the following array of data in php:

```
$arData = [
  [a1, b1, c1, d1],
  [a2, b2, c2, d2]
];
```

For these data we have for each tbl_item_id the following:

1. Valid: It has all the correct combinations of data for every given row (and more, but we don't mind).
2. Valid: It has all the correct combinations of data for every given row exactly.
3. Invalid: It has only one of the given combinations.
4. Invalid: It has the required number of rows but the second combination of data is wrong because of column tbl_data_c.

So the result must contain the ids 1 and 2.

---

Thank you all.

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `tbl_item_id = 2` only ? `tbl_item_id = 1` is breaking point1 and 2 , because you have a row `tbl_id = 3` which does not satisfy any of the given combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can construct the query as:

```
SELECT tbl_item_id 
FROM t 
WHERE (tbl_data_a, tbl_data_b, tbl_data_c, tbl_data_d) IN 
        ( ('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2') )
GROUP BY tbl_item_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that your table has no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT tbl_item_id 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY tbl_item_id 
HAVING 
  SUM(tbl_data_a = 'a1' AND tbl_data_b = 'b1' AND tbl_data_c = 'c1' AND tbl_data_d = 'd1') 
AND 
  SUM(tbl_data_a = 'a2' AND tbl_data_b = 'b2' AND tbl_data_c = 'c2' AND tbl_data_d = 'd2')
```

Comment: This works as well as Gordon's answer, but unfortunately I can only mark one as correct. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Thanasis no worries, please update the question, as correct answer would only be `item_id = 1`

Comment: No, we don't mind for extra rows. Both 1 and 2 are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
select yt1.tbl_item_id from your_table yt1
inner join your_table yt2 on yt1.tbl_item_id = yt2.tbl_item_id
where yt1.tbl_data_a = 'a1' and yt1.tbl_data_b = 'b1' and yt1.tbl_data_c = 'c1' and yt1.tbl_data_d = 'd1'
and yt2.tbl_data_a = 'a2' and yt2.tbl_data_b = 'b2' and yt2.tbl_data_c = 'c2' and yt2.tbl_data_d = 'd2'
```